# Overleaf doesn't add my bibliography to template

Tags: bibtex, templates, overleaf

I'm trying to edit a [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-networks-journal-submission/ctwzchygvcwp), but if I add bibliography (to the  *sample.bib* file) it isn't added to the PDF file when compiling. Also if I delete all the original references, mine doesn't appear.

Some of the original references are:

```
@article{Adams,
    title = {{Optimizing the flow in multicommodity networks with parametric link capacity}},
    author = {A. Adams and B. Gomez and C. Jones and M. Zhang},
    journal = {Operations Research},
    volume = "64",
    number = "2",
    pages = "200--219",
    year = "2016"}

@book{vonNeumann,
    Address = {Princeton, NJ},
    Author = {J. von Neumann and O. Morgenstern},
    Publisher = {Princeton University Press},
    Title = {Theory of Games and Economic Behavior},
    Year = {1953}}
```

and I tried to add

```
@article{mapping,
    author= {Yandong Xiao and Marco Tulio Angulo and Jonathan Friedman and Matthew K. Waldor and Scott T. Weiss and Yang-Yu Liu},
    title= {Mapping the ecological networks of microbial communities},
    journal={Nature Communications},
    volume= "8",
    number= "2042",
    year="2017",
    DOI="doi:10.1038/s41467-017-02090-2"
}

@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
```

Is there a probllem with my bibliography? I guess no, because I took the Einstein reference from an [example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you cite the new references, `mapping` and `einstein`? Usually only references are included in the bibliography that are actually cited.

Comment: a .bib file is a database of all _possible_ references,  adding an entry has no effect on the document (normally) unless you `\cite` the entry.

Comment: Thank you! I had not quoted mapping neither einstein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The references contained in the `.bib` file are shown only if they are cited with  `\cite` in the `.tex` file.

Comment: And if you want everything in the `.bib` file to appear in the bibliography, put `\nocite{*}` in your document.